# Inserting \\ with a command doesn't do the same thing as inserting it directly

Tags: line-breaking

I'm using the [`mathpartir`](http://pastebin.com/sX8dSY81) package and I have some code generated (by LyX) that puts an environment (that I'll call `lines`) in the `\inferrule*` and it seems to bother `pdflatex` whenever there are more than two lines (separated by `\\`) in it. I tried several things but couldn't make anything compile as long as there was a `\\` separating two lines in a `lines` environment.

The following code is exactly the one I uploaded on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/yBfm1zQ0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testa}{
  This is the intended use:
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      1\\
      2
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\newcommand{\testb}{
  % LaTeX Error: \begin{mathpar} on input line 68 ended by \end{lines}. [\testb]
  But (because the code is generated), I have an environment in the rule:
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\\
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\newcommand{\testc}{
  If \textbackslash\textbackslash is renamed \textbackslash{}plop, it works (or well, the output isn't what is expected but I know how to fix it and at least it compiles):

  \newcommand{\plop}{\\\relax}
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\plop
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\newcommand{\testd}{
  % LaTeX Error: \begin{mathpar} on input line 70 ended by \end{lines}. [\testd]
  And it's not the \textbackslash{}relax that fixes it:
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\\\relax
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

% Line 66
%\testa
\testb
%\testc
%\testd


\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: the package from [here?](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) it doesn't seem to be on ctan or in texlive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I've juste uploaded it [here](http://pastebin.com/sX8dSY81).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an environment is a group so your code is like

```
 {#1\\#2}
```

which doesn't work, you can define a non-environment that defeats the grouping so the definition is more like

```
{}#1\\#2{}
```

with two spurious empty groups rather than a group around the whole thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testa}{
  This is the intended use:
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      1\\
      2
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{lines}{\endgroup}{\begingroup\def\@currenvir{lines}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\testb}{
  % LaTeX Error: \begin{mathpar} on input line 68 ended by \end{lines}. [\testb]
  But (because the code is generated), I have an environment in the rule:
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\\
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\newcommand{\testc}{
  If \textbackslash\textbackslash is renamed \textbackslash{}plop, it works (or well, the output isn't what is expected but I know how to fix it and at least it compiles):

  \newcommand{\plop}{\\\relax}
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\plop
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

\newcommand{\testd}{
  % LaTeX Error: \begin{mathpar} on input line 70 ended by \end{lines}. [\testd]
  And it's not the \textbackslash{}relax that fixes it:
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      \begin{lines}
        1\\\relax
        2
      \end{lines}
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}

% Line 66
%\testa
\testb
%\testc
%\testd


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I found another way to make it work (see my answer) but I don't understand it (at all). Could you take a look?

Comment: @xavierm02 sorry had a quick look but too much code in that package for me to debug for fun:-)

Comment: Since I'm now using your fix I'd really like to understand it. The thing I don't understand is the `@currenvir`. Doesn't your code do `{}#1\\#2{\def\@currenvir{lines}}`? And if so what's the point of putting the `@currenvir` there? I would've expected it to be right before the `#1` but if I move it there it fails to compile.

Comment: @xavierm02 `\@currenvir` stops being `lines` at the `\endgroup` in the begin code of the environment, so if you don't put it back then `\end{lines}` will generate an error about the environment name not matching. (try it and see:-)

Comment: Ok thanks. Isn't it safer to use `\newenvironment{lines}{\endgroup\def\@currenvir{lines}}{\begingroup\def\@currenvir{lines}}` then? Or is `\end` the only thing that ever uses `@currenvir`?

Comment: @xavierm02 late reply, no as then the `\@currenvir` definition would extend to the rest of the document after the `\end{lines}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix but I don't understand it >_<

```
\newcommand{\teste}{
  I finally found a fix. Apparently, \textbackslash{}inferrule* doesn't like having several things in its content so if you wrap everything in \{...\}, it works...
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{
      {
        \begin{lines}
          1\\
          2
        \end{lines}
      }
    }{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}
```

The weirdest thing is that if the two { touch each other and so do the }, it fails >_<

```
\newcommand{\teste}{
  I finally found a fix. Apparently, \textbackslash{}inferrule* doesn't like having several things in its content so if you wrap everything in \{...\}, it works...
  \newenvironment{lines}{}{}
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*{{
      \begin{lines}
        1\\
        2
      \end{lines}
    }}{
      3
    }
  \end{mathpar}
}
```

Comment: In the end this doesn't really work because when a rule has many premises, it seems to prevent it front writing them on two lines.